# Nilpotent Lie Algebra with determinant 0

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

If I have a nilpotent Lie Algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and a representation $\rho(X)$ in a vector space $V$ such that $det \rho(X) = 0 $ for all $X \in \mathfrak{g}$, then how do I show that there is a vector $v \in V$ such that $\rho(X)v = 0$ for all $X \in \mathfrak{g}$? I know it involves Engel's theorem but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Where exactly did you find this question ?

Comment: Varadarajan's book.

Comment: Where exactly in Varadajan's book ? I already searched for it there, and could not find it. Ah, you are right - page $251$. It should follow from Theorem $3.5.2$ in Varadarajan somehow.

Comment: Chapter 3, Question 21.

Comment: Can you tell me if you prove it? I'm stuck on this. I think it has something to do with writing down the flag decomposition.